# VBA using .Formula in Excel returns 0 when the Range.Value is Empty

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

if the result of the `.Formula = "='C:\data\[adxl364.xls]ADXL364_QC'!A1"` is empty, it returns a value of `0` in my `Worksheet`.

what should I add to the code for it not to return a value of `0` when the `Cell` is empty?

```
Sub GetRange()
    With Range("A:Z")
        .Formula = "='C:\data\[adxl364.xls]ADXL364_QC'!A1"
        .Formula = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function: `=IF(ISBLANK('C:\data\[adxl364.xls]ADXL364_QC'!A1);"";'C:\data\[adxl364.xls]ADXL364_QC'!A1)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your formula to return an empty string when "..!A1" does not = 0.

```
Sub GetRange()
    With Range("A:Z")
        .Formula = "=If('C:\data\[adxl364.xls]ADXL364_QC'!A1 > 0,'C:\data\[adxl364.xls]ADXL364_QC'!A1,Text(,))"
        .Formula = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

---

I use Text(,) to return an empty string instead of doubling up the double quotation marks (e.g. """"):

```
"=If('C:\data\[adxl364.xls]ADXL364_QC'!A1 > 0,'C:\data\[adxl364.xls]ADXL364_QC'!A1,"""")"
```

Comment: thank you @Thomas Inzina, this is also what have I been trying to do. However, didn't work.

Comment: =IF('C:\data\[adxl364.xls]ADXL364_QC'!A1=0,"",'C:\data\[adxl364.xls]ADXL364_QC'!A1)